# Double sum: $\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^i j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have been trying to solve for $\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^i j$

I was given the answer = 10 but I am not sure how to even begin.

Tried  $\sum_{i=1}^3 (1+2+3+\cdots+i)$ so far but it doesn't seem right. Could someone provide some tips please? Thanks!

Comment: $1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3) = \ldots$?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i j =\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {i^2+i}2=\frac 1 2 \sum_{i=1}^n (i^2+i)=\frac 1 2 \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 +\sum_{i=1}^n i$

Answer (score 1):

First, we have $\sum_{j = 1}^{i} = 1 + 2 + ... + i = \frac{i(i + 1)}{2}$. Then:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{i} j = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{i(i + 1)}{2} = \frac{1(1 + 1)}{2} + \frac{2(2 + 1)}{2} + \frac{3(3 + 1)}{2} = 1 + 3 + 6 = \boxed{10}$$

This approach is most useful when large values of $i$, $j$ are present. A more efficient way to calculate it here is simply $1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 2 + 3) = 10$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand this approach better and I'll be using it in the future.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but would  $\sum_{j=0}^i j$ = $\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$ too? Since if I sub in each individual value it would be 0 + 1 + 2 +... + i? Or would it be $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} j$

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it. Been struggling with summations for awhile!

Answer (score 0):

It's $\sum\limits_{j=1}^1 j+\sum\limits_{j=1}^2 j+\sum\limits_{j=1}^3 j = 1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)=10$.

Answer (score 0):

"Solve for" is the wrong term. If you're given $3x+5=9$ and you're trying to find $x$ then you are **solving** that equation **for** $x.$ But if you're wondering what number $17\times43$ is, then you're **evaluating** that **expression.**

When $i=1$ then $\sum_{j=1}^i j = 1.$

When $i=2$ then $\sum_{j=1}^i j = 1 + 2.$

When $i=3$ then $\sum_{j=1}^i j = 1 + 2 + 3.$

So $\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^i j = 1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3). $